# Windows Phone 8.1 Grid Row Auto Scroll

Tags: xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, silverlight-5.0

I have created Page where there is grid with three rows. In first row I have two button working as Toggle button. This button will visible or collapsed the content of the second and third row.

In second row I have form bigger than screen and in third row there ListView with Sticky and Grouped Style Header

Now the issue is that as the content in second grid row is more I have kept Page level scroll but when I put page level scroll than it will stop sticky header effect in ListView and when I remove page level scroll then ListView sticky header starts working properly but second row which have form bigger than screen will not scroll. So I was looking something that make my second row auto scroll.

Please somebody help to resolve it.

`My XAML Code`

```
<Page.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button" x:Name="ToggleButtonStyle">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="195"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Copperplate Gothic Light"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#0c3757"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid Background="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                        Height="40">
                            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="ButtonTextElement" Foreground="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                            Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Name="Label">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="6,6"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Name="Text">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="6,0"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#e6e6e6"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button" x:Name="DropDownButton">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#e6e6e6"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{Binding Margin}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="35">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                            Stretch="None" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="ButtonTextElement" 
                         Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                         Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Grid.Column="1" 
                         VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" />
                            <Image Source="{TemplateBinding local:BookAFlight.ImageSource}" 
                                         Stretch="Uniform" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                         Height="35"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <!--KAC Offices Style-->
        <Style x:Key="RegionContainerStyle" TargetType="ListViewHeaderItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="RegionTemplate">
            <Border Background="Red">
                <TextBlock Foreground="White" FontSize="28"
                                     Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="CityTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="24" MaxWidth="320" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
                                 Foreground="Black"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <model:GroupedModel x:Key="VM"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CVS" Source="{Binding Regions, Source={StaticResource VM}}"
                              IsSourceGrouped="True"
                              ItemsPath="Cities"/>
    </Page.Resources>
    <!--<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FFFFFF">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Content="$$Contact Us$$" x:Name="btnContactUs" x:Uid="ContactUs"
                Style="{StaticResource ToggleButtonStyle}" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="White"
                Margin="7,7,0,0" Click="ContactUs_Click" Background="#0c3757" />
            <Button Content="$$KACOffices$$" x:Name="KACOffices" x:Uid="KACOffices" Foreground="Gray"
                Style="{StaticResource ToggleButtonStyle}" Grid.Column="1"
                Margin="0,7,7,0" Click="KACOffices_Click"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="grdContactUs" Visibility="Visible">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!--<StackPanel x:Name="spContactUs" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto">-->
                <TextBlock x:Uid="FullName" Text="$$Full Name$$" Grid.Row="0"
                                 Style="{StaticResource Label}"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="FullName" Style="{StaticResource Text}" Grid.Row="1" KeyDown="FullName_KeyDown"/>
                <TextBlock x:Uid="Company" Text="$$Company$$" Grid.Row="2"
                                 Style="{StaticResource Label}"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="Company" Style="{StaticResource Text}" Grid.Row="3" KeyDown="Company_KeyDown"/>
                <TextBlock x:Uid="Telephone" Text="$$Telephone$$" Grid.Row="4"
                                 Style="{StaticResource Label}"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="Telephone" Style="{StaticResource Text}" Grid.Row="5" KeyDown="Telephone_KeyDown"/>
                <TextBlock x:Uid="Email" Text="$$Email$$" Grid.Row="6"
                                 Style="{StaticResource Label}"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="Email" Style="{StaticResource Text}" Grid.Row="7" KeyDown="Email_KeyDown"/>
                <TextBlock x:Uid="ContactArea" Text="$$Contact Area$$" Grid.Row="8"
                                 Style="{StaticResource Label}"/>
                <Grid Grid.Row="9" Height="35">
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource DropDownButton}" x:Name="ContactArea" 
              local:BookAFlight.ImageSource="/Assets/drop-down-icon.png" Margin="6,0">
                        <Button.Flyout>
                            <ListPickerFlyout x:Name="contactAreaListPicker" ItemsSource="{Binding ContactAreas}">
                                <ListPickerFlyout.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel>
                                            <TextBlock>
                                                <Run Text="{Binding contactArea}"/>
                                            </TextBlock>
                                            <Line X1="0" X2="480" Y1="0" Y2="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="LightGray" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListPickerFlyout.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListPickerFlyout>
                        </Button.Flyout>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
                <TextBlock x:Uid="Occupation" Text="$$Occupation$$" Grid.Row="10"
                                 Style="{StaticResource Label}"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="Occupation" Style="{StaticResource Text}" Grid.Row="11" KeyDown="Occupation_KeyDown"/>
                <TextBlock x:Uid="Comments" Text="$$Comments$$" Grid.Row="12"
                                 Style="{StaticResource Label}"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="Comments" Style="{StaticResource Text}" Grid.Row="13"
                                 AcceptsReturn="True" Height="80"/>
                <Button x:Name="Submit" x:Uid="Submit" Background="#0c3757" Grid.Row="14" 
                                Foreground="White" Content="$$Submit$$" Margin="25,0,25,0"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Click="Submit_Click"/>
            <!--</StackPanel>-->
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" x:Name="grdKACOffices" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <lv:DebugListView x:Name="TheListView"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CVS}}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CityTemplate}">
                <ListView.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource RegionTemplate}"
                                                HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource RegionContainerStyle}"/>
                </ListView.GroupStyle>
            </lv:DebugListView>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <!--</ScrollViewer>-->
```

P.S. :- It is Silverlight windows phone 8.1 application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple solution would be to put the just `Grid` in your second row into a `ScrollViewer`.

It will work but the user experience would be really, having a page with two separate scrollable parts. I would suggest you split to page into two separate pages, one with the `Grid` from the second row and another with the `ListView` from the third row.